# Creating html file in specific folder

Tags: xcode

I am new to xcode and am working on an existing application someone created with cordova. I am trying to create a new .html file in the `www` folder but every time I try and create a file, it spits it out into the main folder and I can't drag into it. I've tried adding the file in www but it doesn't show up nor does duplicating an existing (coupons.html) work either. Can anyone explain to me how I can add the .html file into the www folder?

[image]

Comment: select any html file under www folder, right click --> show in finder
,finder window will open then create a new file.

Comment: worked this time, that's strange. Thanks!